# Get id of newly added object by Id (using facade)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I want to get Id of newly added row in database. here is the code:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $me = Translation::save();
        return $me->id;

    }
```

Translation extends Facade
but this code returns error :

> Trying to get property of non-object.

any idea? var_dump($me) returns bool(true)

tricky part is that Translation model contains only 1 column - id

Comment: `save()` returns a boolean in order to tell you whether storing was successful or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new object first in order to save it and retrieve its ID.

```
$me = new Translation();
$me->save();

return $me->id;
```

Comment: Yes but I said I am using laravel Facade, I don't want to have "new" in Translation.

Comment: Okay, where are you setting the id of $me?